# Type=Segmentation error Windows_ExceptionCode=c0000139 in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed Eclipse IDE and try to run a simple Helloworld Java program. But I am facing a below unhandled exception. It happens once in a while when I try to run.

> Unhandled exception  Type=Segmentation error vmState=0x00000000
> Windows_ExceptionCode=c0000139 J9Generic_Signal=00000004
> ExceptionAddress=00007FFA4A352856 ContextFlags=0010004f
> Handler1=00007FF9D51EC9F0 Handler2=00007FFA0EAEAA50
> RDI=00000161EA87AB78 RSI=00007FFA4A36D390 RAX=0000000000000000
> RBX=0000000000000001 RCX=0000000000000002 RDX=0000000000000000
> R8=00007FFA47AF6C4C R9=0000000000000000 R10=0000000000000000
> R11=0000003B3D3ED788 R12=0000000000000003 R13=0000000000000003
> R14=00007FFA17F1CE01 R15=0000000000000003 RIP=00007FFA4A352856
> RSP=0000003B3D3EC0F0 RBP=0000003B3D3EC790 EFLAGS=0000059800000206
> FS=0053 ES=002B DS=002B XMM0 00000161ec2395d0 (f: 3961755136.000000,
> d: 7.510219e-312) XMM1 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
> XMM2 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00) XMM3
> 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00) XMM4 0000000000000000
> (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00) XMM5 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d:
> 0.000000e+00) XMM6 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00) XMM7 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00) XMM8
> 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00) XMM9 0000000000000000
> (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00) XMM10 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d:
> 0.000000e+00) XMM11 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00) XMM12 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00) XMM13
> 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00) XMM14 0000000000000000
> (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00) XMM15 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d:
> 0.000000e+00) Module=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll Module_base_address=00007FFA4A250000 Offset_in_DLL=0000000000102856
> Target=2_90_20220817_464 (Windows 10 10.0 build 19044) CPU=amd64 (16
> logical CPUs) (0x7eeec3000 RAM)
> ----------- Stack Backtrace -----------

I have IBM_semeru_jdk_11 as default jdk and executing this project with IBM_semeru_jdk_8. Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: Can you post source code of your program? How do you run it? Also, do you have to use IBM JDK? What about Open JDK?